# Not sure which audio device to pass through via OVMF

Tags: arch-linux, audio, virtual-machine, pci

I'm configuring a VGA passthrough on Arch for a virtual Windows machine, and when I use `lspci | grep Audio`, I get two different devices with different PCI IDs. They look very similar, and I'm not sure which one to pass through. The output of the above command is this: `00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)`. I don't know if it's arbitrary or if I have to pass a specific one through. Please help.